# JSON Reply contains extra array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm a new Bie to PHP . In the following JSON RESPONSE I had marked with an <----.
I don't want that extra array nor unable to figure out how it is getting added.
Please help.
Thank's in Advance.

The innerloop that iterates 15 times is giving the issue.
I'm appending arrays here ..

```
<?php
function getUserDetails($regno){
    $UserDetails = array();//return value;
    $UserDetails["number"] = $regno;
    $UserDetails["cgpa"] = "8.5";
    $UserDetails["rank"] = "87";
    $UserDetails["overview"] = null;
    $subjects_codes = array("Sub1","Sub2","Sub3","Sub4","Sub5","Sub6","Sub7","Sub8","Sub9","Sub10","Sub11","Sub12",null,"TPC","TCC","Percentage");
    $subjects_attendance = array("sub1","sub2","sub3","sub4","sub5","sub6","sub7","sub8","sub9","sub10","sub11","sub12","sub13","200","200","100");
    $attendanceAllSubjects[] = array();
    for($i=0;$i<=15;$i++){
        if($subjects_codes[$i] == null){
            continue;
        }
        $attendanceSingleSubject = array();
        $attendanceSingleSubject["code"] = $subjects_codes[$i];
        $attendanceSingleSubject["att"] = $subjects_attendance[$i];
        $attendanceAllSubjects[] = $attendanceSingleSubject;
    }
    $UserDetails["overview"] = $attendanceAllSubjects;
    return json_encode(array("user" => $UserDetails));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(getUserDetails("Y17CS151"));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

JSON RESPONSE :

```
{
"user": {
"number": "Y17CS151",
"cgpa": "8.5",
"rank": "87",
"overview": [
[],<---- EXTRA ARRAY
{
"code": "Sub1",
"att": "sub1"
},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{
"code": "Sub10",
"att": "sub10"
},
{},
{},
{
"code": "TPC",
"att": "200"
},
{
"code": "TCC",
"att": "200"
},
{
"code": "Percentage",
"att": "100"
}
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `[]` from `$attendanceAllSubjects[] = array();` and remove `$UserDetails["overview"] = null;` .Then you are good to go.

***For me a  more cleaner way to do it:***

```
<?php
function getUserDetails($regno){

    $UserDetails = array();//return value;

    $UserDetails["number"] = $regno;

    $UserDetails["cgpa"] = "8.5";

    $UserDetails["rank"] = "87";

    $subjects_codes = array("Sub1","Sub2","Sub3","Sub4","Sub5","Sub6","Sub7","Sub8","Sub9","Sub10","Sub11","Sub12",null,"TPC","TCC","Percentage");

    $subjects_attendance = array("sub1","sub2","sub3","sub4","sub5","sub6","sub7","sub8","sub9","sub10","sub11","sub12","sub13","200","200","100");

    for($i=0; $i<=15; $i++){

        if($subjects_codes[$i] == null){

            continue;
        }

        $UserDetails["overview"][] = array(
            "code" => $subjects_codes[$i],
            "att" => $subjects_attendance[$i]
        );
    }

    return json_encode(array("user" => $UserDetails));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(getUserDetails("Y17CS151"));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou @Anant Singh.. It Worked and I have changed to a more clearer code as you said.Thanks !

Comment: @SarathKumarMannam  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `[]` from you **attendanceAllSubjects** declaration so it will look like this `$attendanceAllSubjects = array();` instead of `$attendanceAllSubjects[] = array();`